# How to splice a list within a data-mask

Tags: r, purrr, rlang

In the example below (which only serves to illustrate the issue), I try to use `coalesce()` on all columns starting with "Age" to construct a new column.

Both `invoke()` and `do.call()` work as expected because they accept a list. Seeing that `invoke()` is deprecated, I tried to follow the suggestion to use `rlang::exec()` instead. However, `rlang::exec()` needs to explicitly slice the arguments contained in the list with `!!!` – which works with an entire dataframe but not within the data-masking function below. Is there a way to make it work?

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Condition, ~Age...2, ~Age...3, ~Age...4,
  1,       18,       NA,       NA,
  1,       19,       NA,       NA,
  2,       NA,       20,       NA,
  2,       NA,       21,       NA,
  3,       NA,       NA,       22,
  3,       NA,       NA,       23
)

# works, but with warning
mutate(df, new = invoke(coalesce, pick(starts_with("Age"))))
#> Warning: There was 1 warning in `mutate()`.
#> ℹ In argument: `new = invoke(coalesce, pick(starts_with("Age")))`.
#> Caused by warning:
#> ! `invoke()` was deprecated in purrr 1.0.0.
#> ℹ Please use `exec()` instead.
#> # A tibble: 6 × 5
#>   Condition Age...2 Age...3 Age...4   new
#>       <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1         1      18      NA      NA    18
#> 2         1      19      NA      NA    19
#> 3         2      NA      20      NA    20
#> 4         2      NA      21      NA    21
#> 5         3      NA      NA      22    22
#> 6         3      NA      NA      23    23

# does not work
mutate(df, new = exec(coalesce, pick(starts_with("Age"))))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 5
#>   Condition Age...2 Age...3 Age...4 new$Age...2 $Age...3 $Age...4
#>       <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>       <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1         1      18      NA      NA          18       NA       NA
#> 2         1      19      NA      NA          19       NA       NA
#> 3         2      NA      20      NA          NA       20       NA
#> 4         2      NA      21      NA          NA       21       NA
#> 5         3      NA      NA      22          NA       NA       22
#> 6         3      NA      NA      23          NA       NA       23
mutate(df, new = exec(coalesce, !!!pick(starts_with("Age"))))
#> Error in `pick()`:
#> ! Must only be used inside data-masking verbs like `mutate()`,
#>   `filter()`, and `group_by()`.

#> Backtrace:
#>      ▆
#>   1. ├─dplyr::mutate(df, new = exec(coalesce, !!!pick(starts_with("Age"))))
#>   2. ├─dplyr:::mutate.data.frame(df, new = exec(coalesce, !!!pick(starts_with("Age"))))
#>   3. │ ├─dplyr:::mutate_cols(.data, dplyr_quosures(...), by)
#>   4. │ │ └─base::force(dots)
#>   5. │ └─dplyr:::dplyr_quosures(...)
#>   6. │   └─rlang::quos(..., .ignore_empty = "all")
#>   7. └─dplyr::pick(starts_with("Age"))
#>   8.   └─dplyr:::peek_mask()
#>   9.     └─dplyr:::context_peek(...)
#>  10.       ├─context_peek_bare(name) %||% ...
#>  11.       └─rlang::abort(glue("Must only be used inside {location}."), call = call)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: `library(dplyr) df %>% mutate(new = coalesce(!!!select(., starts_with("Age"))))`

Answer (score 2):

We could use

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
  mutate(new = exec(coalesce, 
!!! rlang::syms(names(select(., starts_with("Age"))))))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 5
  Condition Age...2 Age...3 Age...4   new
      <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
1         1      18      NA      NA    18
2         1      19      NA      NA    19
3         2      NA      20      NA    20
4         2      NA      21      NA    21
5         3      NA      NA      22    22
6         3      NA      NA      23    23
```